# What is included in DbContext model?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

**Description:** 
I've tried to separate certain domain segments into different `DbContext`s.

Each has several `DbSet`s, but there are some `DbSet`s that are shared, for example the `UserProfile`.

The reason for this separation is the speed at which the model is generated and the simplicity (less sets in an object, helps with intellisense).

However, I am not sure about what exactly belongs to the model that is generated.

**Q1:** Is every entity that is transitionally connected with the entities, for which a DbSet exists in a DbContext, included in the model?

**Q2:** If so, would that mean that performance-wise it serves no purpose to separate the domain into different contexts, since everything that is connected ends up in the model anyway, no matter which `DbSet`s are stated in the `DbContext`?

Where can I find more information on how the model is generated? I've read a book on EntityFramework and CodeFirst and couldn't find that specific information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your **first question**: yes, all relations are modeled including the entities on both sides, so every entity that's connected by a navigation property to an included entity will also be included in the model regardless if there's a `DbSet` for it or not.

Entity Framework doesn't force you to create `DbSets` for all entities. This can be handy if you want to "restrict" child entities to only be accessible through their parents.

Regarding your **second question**: separating your contexts might still improve performance, if not all entities belonging to one context are reachable via navigation properties of entities belonging to the other context. There *could* be an additional cost associated with explicitly including more `DbSets` in a context, too.

You could read (some parts of) the Entity Framework source code, it's open-source and available [on CodePlex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/) to learn more about how the model is built.